# C# language - usage of "this" keyword

Tags: c#, this

What is meaning of `: this(data, null)` in below given code?

```
public class Node<T>
{
        // Private member-variables
        private T data;
        private NodeList<T> neighbors = null;

        public Node() {}
        public Node(T data) : this(data, null) {}
```

Comment: It calls the other constructor with 2 parameters, but obviously you have cut that part.

Comment: Thanks, yes there is other constructor with 2 parameters.

Comment: public Node(T data, NodeList<T> neighbors)
        {
            this.data = data;
            this.neighbors = neighbors;
        }